# CefSharp issue in windows7

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am working on an WPF-application where I am using CefSharp as webbrowser. I have integrated it successfully in my application, but its only working in Windows 8.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and CefSharp 1.25.0.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.Installed visual c++ redistributable 2008 and visual c++ redistributable 2010.But still not working..any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try again with CefSharp 1.25.5, and Visual C++ Redistributable **2012**. It should work.

Comment: To fix the fonts issue, use the WinForms control, which renders nicely.

You can use the WinForms control even in a WPF application by using HwndHost

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, since it means you loose a lot of the WPF functionality (transparency, transformations etc).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new nuget package??? It's far more stable and requires no mystical adding of almost random C++ redistributable libs.

Anything >3.0 is good